# What's a more eloquent way to do this?

Tags: vb.net

Is there a better way to code something like this?

```
Dim selectedDisciplines As List(Of ListItem)
dim item1 as integer 
dim item2 as integer 
dim item3 as integer
dim item4 as integer
dim item5 as integer
dim item6 as integer

/*  selectedDisciplines is either filled or not */>

If selectedDisciplines.Count >= 1 Then
    item1 = selectedDisciplines.Item(0).Value
End If
If selectedDisciplines.Count >= 2 Then
    item2 = selectedDisciplines.Item(1).Value
End If
If selectedDisciplines.Count >= 3 Then
    item3 = selectedDisciplines.Item(2).Value
End If
If selectedDisciplines.Count >= 4 Then
    item4 = selectedDisciplines.Item(3).Value
End If
If selectedDisciplines.Count >= 5 Then
    item5 = selectedDisciplines.Item(4).Value
End If
If selectedDisciplines.Count = 6 Then
    item6 = selectedDisciplines.Item(5).Value
End If
```

Comment: How are you using the `item#` variables later?

Comment: Define your concept of _better_ in this context

Comment: It's tempting to just submit the answer "yes" to this question :-)

Comment: Is it *necessary* to have `item1, item2,...item6` or could you use a `List(Of Integer)`?

Comment: Yes.  Dont do it.  The items in the collection are perfectly usable

Comment: test -  They are being passed to an argument that requires either a '0' or the selected value.

Comment: Andrew Morton.  They are being passed to an argument that requires either a '0' or the selected value.

Comment: @RandyAmazing that doesn't answer Andrew's question. Though using a `List(Of Integer)` or an array of integers you can still pass them as arguments.

Comment: Basically the variables are used like so:

subprocedure (item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6)

Comment: @RandyAmazing the only thing you'd have to change is to do for example like this: `SubProcedure(items(0), items(1), items(2), items(3), items(4), items(5))`.

Answer (score 1):

The *eloquent way* is actually this:

```
// removed code was here
```

I think that it is critical to avoid writing this kind of code entirely. Not only is it *superfluous* because you're picking apart a perfectly useful collection, but you're also probably *adding* to the burden associated with maintaining the code if the collection ever needs to have its capacity increased or decreased later on. Finally, you are making the code less readable to others.

You have to fight the urge to only manipulate intrinsic CTS data types (like Integer, String or Boolean).

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to make this "better". Here's my suggestion:

1. Declare an array of `Integers` with the size set to how many you need.
2. Loop through every index, and if `selectedDisciplines.Count` is more or equal to the current index plus one, set the respective integer in the array to the current `selectedDiscipline`'s value.
3. If `selectedDisciplines.Count` is less than the current index, stop the loop.

**Code example:**

```
Dim items(6 - 1) As Integer 'In Visual Basic you should always make it one less than what you want when you're declaring arrays.

For i = 0 To items.Count - 1
    If selectedDisciplines.Count >= (i + 1) Then
        items(i) = selectedDisciplines.Item(i).Value
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

**Example for using these as arguments:**

Later when you'd like to pass these as arguments/parameters you'd only have to do the following:

```
MethodHere(items(0), items(1), items(2), items(3), items(4), items(5)) 'and so on...
```